# What kind of lens does the opposite of magnifying?

Tags: optics, lenses

I am doing an art project, for which I need a lens that has the opposite effect of a magnifying lens, that is, to make whatever you're looking at appear smaller than it actually is.

I am nearsighted, and my eyeglasses do the same effect when I look through them from the front side in.

I know nothing about physics. What kind of lens am I looking for? Convex, concave, ...?

Comment: Do you need a lens that gives you a diminished image of an object *when you look at it through the lens* (a so-called 'virtual' image) or do you want a diminished image *on a screen* such as a piece of paper? This would be a 'real' image.

Answer (score 1):

[Concave](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-5/Diverging-Lenses-Object-Image-Relations) lens produces a diminished and erect virtual image for any position of the object.

If you do not care whether it is virtual and erect, and a real inverted image can do, then you can use a [convex](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/refrn/u14l5db.cfm) lens but the object has to be beyond the first centre of curvature.

Answer (score -1):

Magnification, both +ve and -ve, can be done with either two convex lenses or a concave and convex lens. Two elements are needed as you will want to take parallel beams, do something, then make them parallel again. In the case of the latter, the convex lens converges the light and the concave lens diverges it back to parallel. For the former, light convergent on a focal point diverges therefrom, so a second convex lens can be used after it in order re-parallelise the light.

The amount of magnification can be changed by lens positioning / focal lengths of the system and which way round light travels.

Short-sightedness has nothing to do with magnification, but with where your eye focuses.

Comment: One lens is enough.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens#Magnification.

Comment: Negative magnification means inverted image, not reduced size.

Comment: @nasu : yes. For a "shrinkifying glass", what you need is a magnification that is strictly smaller (i.e. less magnitude) than 1.